# Draw 3D bounding box of object in 2D image OpenCV

Tags: python

Recently I have been interested in Computer Vision and I am now experimenting with OpenCV in Python. I have done some research but haven't really found what I am looking for. Therefore I try to give it a go my own way.

My objective is to have an image where a 3D object is situated in. Of this object I would like to draw a 3D bounding box around it. My idea of accomplishing this is by:

1. Draw a 2D bounding box around the object (green square)
2. Determine corners within the 2D bounding box (red dots)
3. Determine contours withing the 2D bounding box (blue lines)
4. Connect the corners by the contours

The following image illustrates the 4 steps above.

[image: 3D bounding box around object]

I would like to know if this is a possible approach, or if there are better ways to do this? Any suggestions and input is welcome since I'm still pretty new into the field of Computer Vision.

Comment: You ask if this is a possible approach.  Well, of course it is a possible approach -- you just described it, so that makes it possible.  Why don't you try it on some sample images and see how well it works?  If it works, then you've answered your own question.  If it doesn't work, then you will be able to ask a specific question about how to fix the part that doesn't work, or you'll be able to explain how it fails.

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for your comment! As I have stated twice in my post, I am new in the field of CV and have therefore hardly any experience about this topic what so ever. My point is more that I wanted to know if people here, who might be more experienced than me, can propose a better, more efficient way to accomplish my ultimate goal! Global warming can be solved too in multiple ways, but what's the best approach? ;-)

Comment: Computer vision typically involves a good bit of trial and error.  The site works best when you put in a significant amount of effort before asking and can ask about some specific aspect you're having trouble with.  You're asking others to help out, so you can't expect them to try this stuff for you.

Comment: I think that with it is a very good idea. Green box is obvious, all but one red dots are possible and easy, the one at the visible corner (all three edges visible) might be tricky if you cannot guarantee patterns at box. On the other hand, CV takes things for granted and start there. If you guarantee box, then it is possible to reconstruct missing corner and ignore problems, if not, well, corner detector will find many phantom points from patterns and still may leave these corner out. It is far easier to detect box or any of other known types than reconstruct box without assumptions.

Comment: Some details left out may switch it from not possible to trivial. If you can say guarantee that pattern is variable width axis aligned rectangle with exactly one logo, it is super easy. The same for box (simply find it and mark it, do not consider other objects). If this gets to any 3D object without any knowledge in advance, pattern projection will tell where is wall and for other objects it will be probably working.Imagine torus with pattern suggesting corners on it, fails for sure. So for starters specify all data known in advance and for your idea, try it out and then say what failed.